# i am trying to create a c++ snake game but i cant seem to draw the second height border, how do i fix this?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// player cordinates
int x, y;
// fruit cordinates
int fruitX, fruitY;

void setup() {
    int height = 20, width = 20;
    for (int x = 1; x < height; x++) {

        cout << "#";
    }
    for (int x = 1; x < height; x++) {

        cout << "#" << endl;
    }
        for (int x = 1; x < width; x++) {
            cout << "#";
        }




}
int main() {

    setup();
}
```

for convenience, i am gonna shorten the number of hashes, but here is the output:

```
######
#
######
```

i dont know how to print the second height border, how do i achieve this?

Comment: Recommend building a 2D array in memory. Write the board, and in-game items to that memory, and then write that memory to the screen

Answer (score 1):

You need to think in printing in rows

```
void setup()
{
    int height = 20, width = 20;

    // print top row
    std::cout << std::string(width, '#') << '\n';

    // print middle rows
    for (int i = 0; i < height - 2; ++i)
         std::cout << '#' << std::string(width - 2, ' ') << "#\n";

    // print bottom row
    std::cout << std::string(width, '#') << '\n';

    std::cout << std::flush;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your void `setup()` function should have been like show below. while printing boundary of both left and right side. Iterate height 20 times, then in each iteration iterate each columns(i.e. width) and when column value is 1 and 19 i.e first and last then only print '#'.

```
void setup() {
int height = 20, width = 20;
for (int x = 1; x < width; x++) {
    cout << "#";
}
cout<<endl;
for (int x = 1; x < height; x++) {
    for(int i=1;i<width;i++){
        if(i==19 || i==1){
            cout<<"#";
        }
        else{
            cout<<" ";
        }
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
   for (int x = 1; x < width; x++) {
       cout << "#";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As [bolov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2805305/bolov) mentioned, thinking about the content of each row will help.

We are trying to create an NxN grid. An NxN grid is made up of N rows, where each row contains N elements and each element can either be a *#* or empty space.

The first and last rows are entirely made out of # and we have a single # at the start and end of each row between them.

A 3x3 version of this grid looks like the following. I've used the *+* symbol instead of a whitespace character so that it is easier to follow.

```
###
#+#
###
```

A 4x4 grid looks like this:

```
####
#++#
#++#
####
```

A 5x5 grid looks like this:

```
#####
#+++#
#+++#
#+++#
#####
```

In the first row, we use # for each element.

```
for (int i = 0; i < width; ++i)
{
  std::cout << '#';
}

std::cout << std::endl;
```

After that, we need to create `height - 2` rows that have *#* only as their first and last element, leaving us with `width - 2` empty spaces.

```
for (int c = 0; c < height - 2; ++c)
{
  std::cout << '#';

  for (int i = 0; i < width - 2; ++i)
  {
    std::cout << ' ';
  }

  std::cout << '#' << std::endl;
}
```

And finally, we create the last row the same as the first.

```
for (int i = 0; i < width; ++i)
{
  std::cout << '#';
}
```

A working example can be found [here](https://repl.it/@omalinov/overflow).